# Handling a menu click event in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, events, menu

I am trying to set up a click event for a popup menu in Android. I created an overidden `onOptionsItemSelected()`, but nothing seems to be happening. Here is the popupmenu.xml file:

**popupmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="Help" />
<item android:id="@+id/information"
    android:title="Information" />
<item android:id="@+id/services"
    android:title="Services" />
<item android:id="@+id/overdose"
    android:title="Overdose" />
</menu>
```

**Here is the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.help:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Help Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.information:
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Information Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.services:
            Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(this, "Services Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast3.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.overdose:
            Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(this, "Services Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast4.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that `onOptionsItemSelected()` was called whenever a menu item was selected, and that it didn't require the `android:onClick` attribute in the layout for the activity. Is there something I'm missing here? The popup menu works perfectly otherwise.

Comment: Can you post your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: @SavinSharma I think he confused `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as the click listener for `PopupMenu`

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. Thank you for the input anyways!

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: I thought you want to listen for `Toolbar` option's click. Here is
>   how to listen for click events in `PopupMenu`

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                    // get id in item parameter and switch case
                    return true;  
                }  
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think u have to add another method as below. You haven't mentioned above.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

You can add this code in Your MainActivity.java. Or For More refer to this link.
[Android Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#java)